# Change url with ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get, cross-domain

I'm doing cross-domain GET to get cnn html like this:

```
$(function(){

var site = 'http://cnn.com';

$.get('proxy.php', { site:site }, function(data){

$(data).appendTo('#div');

}, 'html');

});
```

Im getting everything that I need except the url's sometimes are not complete urls but point to a certain path on there server like this:

```
/2013/01/24/business/samsung-record-fourth-quarter-2012-profits/index.html?hpt=hp_t3
```

So the problem is that if someone is clicking the link on my site the url will look like this:

```
http://MY-WEBSITE/2013/01/24/business/samsung-record-fourth-quarter-2012-profits/index.html?hpt=hp_t3
```

How can I get rid of my own url being inserted and replace it with 'cnn.com'?
I tried jquery split and replace but it doesn't work:

```
href = $(this).prop('href');
url = href.split('/');          
href.replace(url[2], 'cnn.com');
```

I usually get an error in console 'split is not defined', when I fixed it the error moves on to 'url is not defined' and so on. Sometimes (with other code variations) I get no errors but it still doesn't work. I cant figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried using an IFrame ponting to the CNN site?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check if the url is relative or not.  Easiest way to do this is to check if it starts with `http://`.

```
var url = $(this).prop('href');
if (!(/^http/).test(url)) 
{
    url = site + url; // prepend "http://cnn.com" to the address
}

alert(url); // url is now a full url
```

if you want a more generalised solution, you can use the regexp object on the site to determine if the prefix is there.

```
var site = "http://cnn.com";
var siteRegex = new RegExp("^" + site); // Regex - Starts with site
var url = $(this).prop('href');
if (!siteRegex.test(url))
{
   url = site + url;
}

alert(url);
```

Comment: I like it, its simple. I will test it later on my server

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code I am assuming you are using jQuery.

The problem is occurring because the source code on cnn.com seems to be using relative links. You can insert cnn.com at the beginning with the following jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('a').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('href').indexOf('http') === 0) {
            $(this).attr('href', 'http://www.cnn.com' + this.href);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: the if statement is simply there to make sure it only changes relative links

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/TWK7r/)

Either seems to work:

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
var url = (href.indexOf("/")===0) ? "http://...."+href:href;
```

Possible alternative - this one will return the fully qualified URL from the href

```
var href = this.href; // actual href and not the property
var url =(href.indexOf(location.hostname)===7) ? href.replace(location.hostname,"www.cnn.com"):href;
```

Using prop

```
var href = $(this).prop('href');
var url = (href.indexOf("/")===0) ? "http://...."+href:href;
```

Comment: Im getting this in console: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'prop'

Comment: I did not ask for prop, I asked for a way to do the job. The prop was just something I tried, nothing more. Any way I dont think I can do this with chrome console, I will try later on on my server

Answer (score 0):

This little function can be used in a general purpose:

```
function RelativeToAbsoluteURL(root, url) {
    var httpMatch = /https?:\/\//ig;
    if (!httpMatch.test(url)) {
        return root + (url.substr(0, 1) != "/" ? "/" + url : url);
    } else {
        return url;
    }
}
```

Use:

```
RelativeToAbsoluteURL("http://www.cnn.com", "http://www.cnn.com/2013/01/24/business/samsung-record-fourth-quarter-2012-profits/index.html?hpt=hp_t3");

RelativeToAbsoluteURL("http://www.cnn.com", "/2013/01/24/business/samsung-record-fourth-quarter-2012-profits/index.html?hpt=hp_t3");
```

Both will output the same URL (`http://www.cnn.com/2013/01/24/business/samsung-record-fourth-quarter-2012-profits/index.html?hpt=hp_t3`)